# Error converting nvarchar to numeric for registering record

Tags: c#, sql-server

[Error message converting nvarchar to numeric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiE9p.jpg)

[Table structure in SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6gfE.jpg)

This is the code for the register button

```
private void bttnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student VALUES (@stu_fname, @stu_lname, @Address, @Phone, @Email, @DateOfBirth, @UserName, @Password, @DateAdded)", con);  

        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stu_fname", txtFirstname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stu_lname", txtLastname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DateOfBirth.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Registration Successful!");
        con.Close();

        txtFirstname.Clear(); 
        txtLastname.Clear(); 
        txtAddress.Clear(); 
        txtPhone.Clear();
        txtEmail.Clear(); 
        txtUsername.Clear(); 
        txtPassword.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Read ["Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?"](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). And why is `Phone` `numeric(18,0)`? Phone numbers aren't numbers, they're strings made of  mostly digits, yes. But in a `numeric` leading 0s cannot be stored (001 = 01 = 1) and also a leading + for two leading 0s cannot be in a `numeric`. `numeric` is not the right type for a phone number.

Comment: Sticky bit is correct. Also why use direct sql statements with ado.net and not entity framework or another ORM? Or even a call to a stored procedure at least.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting `txtFirstname.Text`, a string, into the `stu_id` column, which is int. When inserting into a table, I always include the column names because it prevents these kinds of errors, is easier to read and debug, and avoids some problems that can arise when a table structure changes. Assuming `stu_id` is an identity column, your SQL string should be:

```
INSERT INTO Student (stu_fname, stu_lname, Address, Phone, Email, DateOfBirth, Username, Password, DateAdded) VALUES (@stu_fname, @stu_lname, @Address, @Phone, @Email, @DateOfBirth, @UserName, @Password, @DateAdded)
```

Comment: it still has the same result even though I changed the SQL statement

Comment: @RaymondLayosa: Because `Phone` is `numeric` but `AddWithValues` guesses it's a `varchar`. Use `Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.Decimal)`.